# Cardinality of a conic and quadric over the field $\mathbb{F}_9$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following question in an assignment:

Over the field $\mathbb{F}_9$ of nine elements, find the cardinality of

a) the conic $x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{P}_2$

b) the quadric $x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{P}_3$

Any hints on how to proceed? One way would be to just substitute the points of $\mathbb{F}_9=\mathbb{Z_3}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$. But that's way too much computation.

Comment: With [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) it would take only a few minutes. How is that "too much computation"? I would really like to know.

Comment: Presumably the OP means computation by hand.

Comment: Note that these are Fermat curves thus possess a bit more symmetry than usual. This might simplify the computation.

Comment: For (a), if you consider $(x_0, x_1, x_2) = a + bi$ for $a, b \in \Bbb F_3^3$, then you find that $x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 = 0$ means exactly that $\|a\|^2 = \|b\|^2$ and $a \cdot b = 0$. And similarly for (b).

Comment: @Somos:  Without PARI/GP but with a human brain it also takes only a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two degree $2$ varieties  are smooth and contain at least a point over $\mathbb F_9$, say $(1:1:1)$ on the conic and $P=(1:1:1:0)$ on the quadric $\mathcal Q$.
Projecting from that point on the line $x_0=0$ of $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb F_9)$, respectively on the plane $\Pi:x_0=0$ of $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb F_9)$, you will find that over $\mathbb F_9$ your conic has $10$ points and your quadric $100$ points.

**Edit: a few details  for the more difficult case of the quadric**

The tangent plane $T_P$ to the quadric $\mathcal Q$ at $P=(1:1:1:0)$  has equation $T_P: x_0+x_1+x_2=0$.
It cuts the the quadric $\mathcal Q: x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 0$ along the degenerate conic $$x_0+x_1+x_2=0,\quad x_1^2+x_2^2+x_1x_2-x_3^2=(x_1-x_2+x_3)(x_1-x_2-x_3)=0$$ consisting of the union of the lines $$L_1:x_0+x_1+x_2=0,x_1-x_2+x_3=0 \\L_2:x_0+x_1+x_2=0,x_1-x_2-x_3=0$$ 
The projection of our quadric $\mathcal Q$ from its point $P$ to the plane $\Pi: x_0=0$ of $\mathbb P^3$ induces a bijection from $\mathcal Q\setminus (L_1\cup L_2)$ onto the affine plane $\Pi\setminus T_P\cong \mathbb A^2(\mathbb F_9)$.
This accounts for $\vert \Pi\setminus T_P\vert=\vert \mathbb A^2(\mathbb F_9)\vert=9^2=81$ points of the quadric.
To obtain the complete  quadric we have to add the points of $L_1\cup L_2$.
Since there are $19$ of them (union of two $10$-point projective lines meeting in $1$ point) , we see that $\mathcal Q$ contains a total of $$81+19=100$$points over $\mathbb F_9$
The exact same reasoning proves that the quadric $\mathcal Q: x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 0$ in $\mathbb P^3(\mathbb F_q)$ has $q^2+2q+1=(q+1)^2$ points over an arbitrary finite field with $q$ elements $\mathbb F_q$.

Comment: Can you tell me the chain of thought to this approach for the solution? Also, how does $(1:1:1)$ lie on the conic?

Comment: Projecting an algebraic variety on a linear subspace is a standard technique in algebraic geometry, so there was not much original thought in my approach ! The point $(1:1:1)$ is on the conic because $1^2+1^2+1^2=3=0\in \mathbb F_3\subset \mathbb F_9$

Comment: Ah! I see. I'm doing a lot of self-study for this particular course, so this technique might have escaped my notice, though it makes a lot of sense. Can I also ask how do we know that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are 10-point projective lines? And the fact that $\Pi\setminus T_P\cong \mathbb A^2(\mathbb F_9)$ is because, since $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb F_9) = \mathbb A^2(\mathbb F_9) \sqcup \mathbb P^1(\mathbb F_9)$ , and we've projected from a point of infinity

Comment: A projective line is obtained by adding one point to an affine line. And the affine line has the same number of points as the base field, namely $9$ in the case of $\mathbb F_9$. Your last equality in the comment is correct: the projective plane is indeed the disjoint union of an affine plane and a projective line (over any field).

Comment: Using similar arguments for the conic: I will get 9 points, because this time $\Pi\setminus T_P\cong \mathbb A^1(\mathbb F_9)$. And to complete the conic I'll consider the line $L: x_0+x_1+x_2=0,x_1-x_2=0$. But won't this provide me with an additional 10 points? Giving us 19 points? 

I'm also confused on how you arrived at the degenerate conic.

Comment: Sorry, I can't go on answering your questions in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69788/discussion-between-junkquill-and-georges-elencwajg).